# InputStream wrapper access inner stream on error

Tags: java, inputstream, guava, wrapper

my problem is that i need to decode a base64 stream, **and** in case something goes wrong, I need to access that base64 stream to e.g. write it to disk for further analysis.

So, the first part is straightforward. With guava I can do

```
final InputStream dataBase64Stream = httpPost.getResponseBodyAsStream();
final InputStream binaryStream = 
        BaseEncoding.base64().decodingStream(new InputStreamReader(dataBase64Stream));
```

where `httpPost` is from where i get the base64 data (I'm using commons-httpclient's PostMethod here).

Now I pass the `binaryStream` to some other places and there I read it.
My problem now arises if something is wrong with that `binaryStream`.
In my case, it sometimes doesn't consist of base64, but of XML which contains an error message.

So, my question is:
if there is an exception reading from the (inner) `binaryStream`, how can I access that inner `dataBase64Stream` to see what is going on?

- Maybe I can register some sort of exception handler?
- Or maybe i can set some kind of "fallback" stream processor?
- Or maybe there is some composite InputStream implementation where I can add both `binaryStream` for the actual reading and `dataBase64Stream` to have a look if i need to?

Note that if an error occurs, I'm fine with accessing only the *reminder* of `dataBase64Stream` ..no need to rewind back to its start.

So far I considered the following:

- storing `dataBase64Stream`'s content as a temporal file
- creating my own little InputStream which has a getter for the `dataBase64Stream`.

I think both would work, but I would be happy to learn if there is any best practice for this case.

Comment: You should examine the response code before you start decoding the stream.

Comment: thank you for the hint. i'm already doing that. i get a 200, even if the actual data is not the base64 i expect.

Comment: btw, another thing i briefly considered is to use and subclass javax.mail's Base64Encoder, but i would prefer rather not to use that library. Also, i can't use anything from java8 until unbuntu 16.04LTS is released.

Comment: I wouldn't store the content as a temporary file, but I would store it as a local `byte[]` (or even a `String`) until I knew how to properly decode it.

Comment: @tobi42: Guava actually contains a Base64-handling class :  [BaseEncoding](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/io/BaseEncoding.html)

Comment: @LouisWasserman: i'm not sure how big the data amount can be and i don't want to run into an OOME.

Comment: @Henrik: I'm aware of that, but it doesn't give me access to the original stream in case of an exception.

Comment: For now, i settled to store the incoming stream into a file, then open that file and feed it to the base64 decoder. 
Later, if everything went fine, i'm deleting the file. 
If something went wrong, i leave the file for inspection.